# Which version of codenarc will support to Grails 1.3.7?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, static-code-analysis, codenarc

I am trying to implement for my grails project using 1.3.7 version. I am using ant build instead of Gradle build tool. I am not able to find 
Which version of codenarc will support to Grails 1.3.7?

Answer (score 0):

Versions above [0.9](https://github.com/chrismair/GrailsCodeNarcPlugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changes-in-version-09-20-jan-2011) and under [1.0](https://github.com/chrismair/GrailsCodeNarcPlugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-10-sep-2017).